# Extract a part of list based on dynamic input

Tags: java, spring-boot

In my spring boot application, there is a list of type candidate model - List . It has several attributes(id, firstName, lastName, designation and so on).

I would like to obtain another list (List) from the first list, containing only few attributes(id, lastName), and the remaining values set to null.
The required attributes(table columns - id, lastName) are obtained only during runtime. How can this be achieved?

Comment: What do you mean by "only during runtime"? Code always runs at runtime.

Comment: User will specify the required fields during runtime. At compile time, we cannot know which fields or the number fields that would be required.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to create new `Candidates` with the fields set to null.

Assuming your Candidate class looks something like this...

```
public class Candidate {
    private long id;
    private String firstName;
    // etc

    public Candidate(long id, String firstName, String lastName, String designation /* etc */) {
        ...assign fields...
    }

    // Getters...
}
```

You can do something like this...

```
List<Candidate> candidates = getThemSomehow();

List<Candidate> partialCandidates = candidates.stream()
    .map(c -> new Candidate(c.getId(), null, c.getLastName(), null, null))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

---

EDIT:

Why not use a bean introspector?

```
import java.beans.BeanInfo;
import java.beans.IntrospectionException;
import java.beans.Introspector;
import java.beans.PropertyDescriptor;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Candidate> candidates = Arrays.asList(
                new Candidate(1L, "Fred", "West", "Lunatic"),
                new Candidate(2L, "John", "Lennon", "Beatles"),
                new Candidate(3L, "Dave", "Smith", "SomeBlokeIMetDownThePub")
        );

        Set<String> fields = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("id", "firstName", "designation"));

        List<Candidate> partialCandidates = candidates.stream().map(c -> createPartialCopy(c, fields)).collect(Collectors.toList());

        partialCandidates.forEach(System.out::println);
    }

    public static <T> T createPartialCopy(T source, Set<String> properties) {
        BeanInfo beanInfo;

        try {
            beanInfo = Introspector.getBeanInfo(source.getClass());
        } catch (IntrospectionException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Could not introspect " + source, e);
        }

        T copy;

        try {
            copy = (T) source.getClass().newInstance();
        } catch (InstantiationException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Could not instantiate " + source.getClass(), e);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Could not create " + source.getClass() + " no public zero arg constructor.", e);
        }

        properties.stream()
                .flatMap(p -> Arrays.stream(beanInfo.getPropertyDescriptors()).filter(d -> d.getName().equals(p)))
                .forEach(d -> doCopy(d, source, copy));

        return copy;
    }

    private static <T> void doCopy(PropertyDescriptor propertyDescriptor, T source, T copy) {
        try {
            propertyDescriptor.getWriteMethod().invoke(copy, propertyDescriptor.getReadMethod().invoke(source));
        } catch (InvocationTargetException | IllegalAccessException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Could copy property " + propertyDescriptor.getName(), e);
        }
    }

    public static class Candidate {
        private long id;
        private String firstName;
        private String lastName;
        private String designation;

        public Candidate() {

        }

        public Candidate(long id, String firstName, String lastName, String designation) {
            this.id = id;
            this.firstName = firstName;
            this.lastName = lastName;
            this.designation = designation;
        }

        public long getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(long id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public String getFirstName() {
            return firstName;
        }

        public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
            this.firstName = firstName;
        }

        public String getLastName() {
            return lastName;
        }

        public void setLastName(String lastName) {
            this.lastName = lastName;
        }

        public String getDesignation() {
            return designation;
        }

        public void setDesignation(String designation) {
            this.designation = designation;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Candidate{" +
                    "id=" + id +
                    ", firstName='" + firstName + '\'' +
                    ", lastName='" + lastName + '\'' +
                    ", designation='" + designation + '\'' +
                    '}';
        }
    }
}
```

- The objects you are copying must be of a class with a 0-arg constructor.
- You must have getters and setters for all the properties you want to copy.

Prints...

```
Candidate{id=1, firstName='Fred', lastName='null', designation='Lunatic'}
Candidate{id=2, firstName='John', lastName='null', designation='Beatles'}
Candidate{id=3, firstName='Dave', lastName='null', designation='SomeBlokeIMetDownThePub'}
```

Comment: User will specify the required fields for the partial list during runtime. Number of fields user may request is not fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this very easily using java 8.. Refer below :

```
public class Candidate {

    public Candidate() {
        super();
    }

    public Candidate(int id, String firstName) {
        super();
        this.id=id;
        this.firstName=firstName;
    }

    private int id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String designation; 


//getters &setters

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.id +"....FirstName:"+this.firstName+"......LastName:"+this.lastName+"....Designation:"+this.designation;
    }   
}
```

## Test.java

public class Test{

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Candidate> canditates= new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i=1;i<=5;i++){
        Candidate candidate = new Candidate();
        candidate .setId(i);
        candidate .setDesignation("Desig:"+i);
        candidate .setFirstName("FrstName:"+i);
        candidate .setLastName("LastName:"+i);

        canditates.add(candidate );
    }
    System.out.println(canditates);


    List<Candidate> newList=canditates.stream()
            .map(c -> new Candidate(c.getId(), c.getFirstName()))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    System.out.println(newList);

}
```

}